# Im new to javascript how do i fix this?

Tags: javascript

im currently troubleshooting on why prompt 5 doesnt work, when i delete prompt 5 it does work, im sorry i can't describe my problem with depth just looking for help thanks ! but do feel free to ask questions i didn't specify here

````
 <p id="p"> </p>
 <p id="a"> </p>
 <p id="b"> </p>
 <p id="s"> </p>
 
 <button onclick="prompt1();prompt2();prompt3();prompt4();prompt5();"> prompt </button>
 
 <script> 
 
    function prompt1() {
    var lname = prompt("Enter your family name", "Potter");
  if (lname != null) {
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML =
    "Last Name : "+ lname ; 
    }
}

  function prompt2() {
  var fname = prompt ("Enter your first name", "Harry");
  if (fname != null) {
     document.getElementById("b").innerHTML =
    "First Name : " + fname ;  
    }
}
   function prompt3() {
   var st = prompt ("Enter your section", "Gryffindor");
   if (st !=null) { 
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML =
    "Section : " + st; 
    }
} 
    function prompt4() {
    var con = confirm ("Do you want to proceed?");}
    
    function prompt5()
    if (con != null) { alert( "fname + lname + st ") 
    else { document.getElementById("p").innerHTML =
    "You pressed no";
    }
}



</script>
</body>```
````

Comment: `con` doesn’t exist outside `prompt4`

Comment: does that mean i have to delete the "function prompt5()"?

Comment: Try writing the con variable outside from prompt4.It will work on prompt 4 and 5.And also you forgot {} on prompt 5.

Comment: @Flash i placed the var on the <head> <script> but now how do i activate the con in prompt 4

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve,but your code is now working with prompt5.

```
<p id="p"></p>
<p id="a"></p>
<p id="b"></p>
<p id="s"></p>

<button onclick="prompt1();prompt2();prompt3();prompt4();prompt5()">
  prompt
</button>

<script>
  function prompt1() {
    var lname = prompt("Enter your family name", "Potter");
    if (lname != null) {
      document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "Last Name : " + lname;
    }
  }

  function prompt2() {
    var fname = prompt("Enter your first name", "Harry");
    if (fname != null) {
      document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "First Name : " + fname;
    }
  }
  function prompt3() {
    var st = prompt("Enter your section", "Gryffindor");
    if (st != null) {
      document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = "Section : " + st;
    }
  }
  function prompt4() {
    var con = confirm("Do you want to proceed?");
  }

  function prompt5() {
    if (con != null) {
      alert("fname + lname + st ");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "You pressed no";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer has an error. _"ReferenceError: con is not defined"_